# Arango: generate date sequence

Tags: date, sequence, arangodb

Is it's any way to use date as key?
How I can generate dates from specific date to current?

I need to get structure like this:

```
date: "2009-01-01",
processing-status: "1"
data: "MyData"
```

...

```
date: "2015-07-29",
processing-status: "0"
data: "MyData2"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not entire clear to me what the question is, but I'll try.

First, you will need to set up a collection with a unique index on the `date` attribute:

```
var db = require("org/arangodb").db; 
db._create("dates"); 
db.dates.ensureUniqueConstraint("date");
```

After that, you may insert dates using a generator sequence like this:

```
// current date
var now = new Date("2015-08-03 23:59:59Z"); 
// start date
var start = new Date("2015-07-23Z"); 

var dt = start; 
// loop until we have reached the end date
while (dt.getTime() <= now.getTime()) { 
  // insert document into collection using date from sequence
  db.dates.insert({ date: dt.toISOString().substr(0, 10) }); 
  dt = new Date(dt.getTime() + 86400 * 1000); 
};
```

Note that the unique constraint about will create a hash index. That will ensure uniqueness of the `date` attribute values in the collection but does not support sorting. If you require to sort by `date` attribute or run range queries on it, you should rather use a skiplist index on `date`:

```
db.dates.ensureUniqueSkiplist("date");
```

instead of the

```
db.dates.ensureUniqueConstraint("date");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AQL to create documents with a date attribute each, ranging between a start and end date, too:

```
LET ms_per_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
LET date_start = DATE_TIMESTAMP(2014, 12, 24)
LET date_end = DATE_TIMESTAMP(2014, 12, 31) // or DATE_NOW()
LET date_diff_in_days = (date_end - date_start) / ms_per_day

FOR val IN 0..date_diff_in_days
    LET date = SUBSTRING(DATE_ISO8601(val * ms_per_day + date_start), 0, 10)
    INSERT {
        "date": date,
        "processing-status": val % 3,
        "data": CONCAT("My Data ", val % 3 + 1)
    } INTO demo
RETURN UNSET(NEW, "_rev", "_key") # debug output
```